# Can't add a reference to Newtonsoft.Json.dll as it was not built against the Silverlight runtime

Tags: .net, silverlight, visual-studio-2013, json.net

I am having this problem trying to add the DLL to an existing Silverlight project.
I tried installing the latest download: version 6.0.3

I have tried installing from Package Manager but this also fails.

Comment: Try this on a fresh Silverlight project with NuGet. It definitely works.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do that as I am working on a well established application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 6.0.4 released 3rd August 2014 works when I install from NuGet.
One of the fixes which might have been causing the issue I had:

> Fix - Fixed incorrect NuGet targets on .NET 4.5 portable assembly

Not sure what portable assembly is but anyway, it has been added to my main Silverlight application.